# Remove radio buttons where booking already exists

Tags: php, html, sql

I am trying to make my own booking diary with php, sql and html.

I would like to be able to prevent found booking on my booking form by checking my database to see if a record already exists before allowing my insert statement to execute.

I would ideally like to be able to do a select statement to check if a booking already exists. 
IF the TIME AND DATE DOES NOT exist I would like the RADIO BUTTON PRESENT 
ELSE
IF the TIME AND DATE DOES I would like the radio button NOT PRESENT .

I have been thinking long and hard but cannot think of a way to do it.

Please could I have some suggestions on how I can overcome my problem?

Thanks

My SQL Table is as follows
TABLE Bookings(
bDate Date, 
bTime Time,
bName CHAR(30),
bNumber CHAR(30), 
bReg CHAR(30), 
bMakeModel CHAR(30)
)

This is what I have so far, but I can't think how to do it, I think I may be going about this the wrong way and perhaps a incremented for loop would be better suited:

```
<?php 
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Bookings WHERE bDate = '$_POST[bDate]' ORDER      
BY bTime;");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
if $_POST["bDate"] = $row['bDate'] AND $_POST["bTime"] = !$row['bTime']{
<input type="radio" name="bTime" value="08:00:00"> 8:00

}
?>
  <input type="radio" name="bTime" value="08:00:00"> 8:00
  <input type="radio" name="bTime" value="09:00:00"> 9:00
  <input type="radio" name="bTime" value="10:00:00"> 10:00
  <input type="radio" name="bTime" value="11:00:00"> 11:00<br>
  <input type="radio" name="bTime" value="13:00:00"> 13:00
  <input type="radio" name="bTime" value="14:00:00"> 14:00
  <input type="radio" name="bTime" value="15:00:00"> 15:00
  <input type="radio" name="bTime" value="16:00:00"> 16:00<br>
```

Comment: it seems like you're on the right track. What exactly is the problem? What does your database schema look like?

Comment: Can you show us What have u tried till now.. any code??

Answer (score 1):

Until you post some code for a better help, database structure and eventually an exemple of one one or 2 rows. Here are the steps.

For checking part (form) :
If you haven't submitted your form, use AJAX to check in your database.
If you've submitted form, just execute a query on your database.

For SQL part :
A simple count can do the trick (return 0 if no rows found and n if n rows found), but retrieving an ID is better (NULL if no rows found). If you need help on query, describe the table structure, and the fields you are checking.

For the last part (showing or not the label :
In PHP, just need to test your SQL return and implement a condition test on the count value (> 0 or not), or ID (NOT NULL if row found, else NULL).
You can add the radio button (or not) depending of your test result

Tip :
Using ID is better because you can add it in an hidden INPUT tag if you've found a row. If  later you decide to update it, it will be possible with this id.

Edit (with your code now) :
In your PHP code you have many errors :
-> your if condition isn't surrounded by the parentheses
-> Logical operators in PHP statement aren't like in SQL : `AND (SQL) = && (PHP)`
-> Inside your if, the input tag isn't in an echo. input tag is HTML not PHP

Tips :
- Are you sure you have a good connexion (`$con`) ressource to database?
- In sql string no need to add the final semi-colon ";"
- Always about SQL using the star alias in query run slower than enumerating each field. If one day you need to get a huge resultset, it would be an optimization

Answer (score 1):

Seems nobody answered to your question. Here is a little starting code for you. Don't forget to replace with your database server, user, password and database to connect to mysql :

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>sans titre</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Geany 1.23.1" />
</head>

<body>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST">
        <p>Date : <input type="text" id="bDate" name="bDate" value="" /></p>
        <p>Time : <input type="text" id="bTime" name="bTime" value="" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
    <hr />
    <?php
    /* Check if form is submitted */
    if (isset($_POST["bDate"])) {
        // Need a bDate format = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
        if (!preg_match("/^\d{4}\-[0-1][0-9]\-[0-3][0-9]$/", $_POST["bDate"])) {
            printf("dDate pattern error for SQL. Waiting YYYY-MM-DD");
            exit();
        }

        /* Execute query */
        $query = "SELECT `bDate` , `bTime` , `bName` , `bNumber` , `bReg` , `bMakeModel` FROM `Bookings` WHERE `bDate` = '". $_POST["bDate"] . "' ORDER BY 2";
        $result = $mysqli->query($query);

        /* Parsing result set */
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
            printf ("%s (%s)<br />", $row["bDate"], $row["bTime"]);

            if ($_POST["bDate"] ==  $row["bDate"] && $_POST["bTime"] != $row["bTime"]) {
                printf ("<input type=\"radio\" id=\"bTime\" value=\"%s\" /> %s<br />", $row["bTime"], $row["bTime"]);
            }

        }

        /* free result set */
        $result->free();
    }

    /* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();
    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

You have some checking on mysql connection, POST dDate variable. Also use the free once result set is no more necessary. Hope this help you.